# Strings:Not able to change contents of the string in C++

Tags: c++, string

```
int main() {
  std::string s;
  const int p = 4;
  s.resize(p);

  for(int i=0;i<p;i++)
    s[i]='a';
  std::cout << s << std::endl;

  for(int i=0,j=p-1; i>=j; i++,j--) {
    if(i%2 == 0){
      s[i]='a';
      s[j]='a';
    } else {
      s[i]='b';
      s[j]='b';
    }
  }
  std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

#### Expected Output:

```
s="aaaa" // Initially
s="abba" // Expected string after for loop
```

#### Actual Output:

```
s="aaaa" // Initially
s="aaaa" // But contents of s is not modified
```

Initially in the above program string s will contain only a's,then I try to change the contents of s based on some condition.But the contents won't change.

If the string is x="abc" and if I change x[1]='a',x will be modified to x="aac".

Why am I not able to change the content of s in the above program?

Comment: [`p` was what again?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: Oh, and remember that a `std::string` object is by default *empty*, and that *any* indexing into it will be *out of bounds!*

Comment: p is the size that I want my string s to have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop condition is backwards. It should be `i <= j`.

Comment: Damn it!!Thanks a lot!!:p..My code is working fine now!!I was scratching my head for more than 2 hours just because of this silly mistake.

Answer (score 1):

with this code

```
    string s;
    for(i=0;i<p;i++)s[i]='a';
```

You have an empty (size 0) string and start assigning to elements past the end, which causes Undefined Behavior.  In your case, resulting is a garbage string.  You need to resize the string to be large enough before you start indexing into it:

```
    string s;
    s.resize(p);
    for(i=0;i<p;i++)s[i]='a';
```

Comment: I have added s.resize(p) but still the contents are not modified!!